# get index and add value to equivalent index

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox, indexing

all i want here is to add value to index. for example i have a listbox and i put string to it using the `collections in the properties`, and if i choose the first string with index of 0 and then output an equivalent price..

**like this;**

```
Cheese cake = $200.00
chocolate cake =$100.00
strawberry cake =400.00
```

**here is my work:**

```
public void Computation(Form1 form1) {

        String price1 = form1.listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        form1.listBox2.Items.Add(price1);

    }
```

this output the index but i don't know how to put equivalent price to that index. please help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have an array of prices or some other method to look up the price. For example, if your array of prices looks like this:

```
decimal[] prices = new decimal[] {200, 100, 400};
```

then you can change your code as follows:

```
public void Computation(Form1 form1) {
    String price1 = prices[form1.listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    form1.listBox2.Items.Add(price1);
}
```

Of course the `prices` must contain as many items as `listBox1`, otherwise you will get "index out of range" exceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm so glad i came here to post a question.. :)

Comment: i tried it with combobox but it output different result:   `double[] prices2 = new double[] { 200.01, 100.32, 400.99, 250.12, 500.50 };`  `String price2= prices2[form1.comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
      form1.listBox2.Items.Add(prices2);`  it output `Double[]Array`

Comment: @MarilouMagat You wrote `prices2` instead of `price2`. Should be `form1.listBox2.Items.Add(price2);`

Comment: last question! what if i try this using radiobutton. how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recover the Price part of the selected item string you could write

```
public void Computation(Form1 form1) 
{
     if(form1.listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
     {
         String row = form1.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
         String[] parts = row.Split('=');
         form1.listBox2.Items.Add(parts[1]);
     }
}
```

Caveats: Your listbox strings are all in the form `<cakename>=<price>`, your listbox `SelectionMode` is `SelectionMode.One`